# In MySQL is it possible to have a NULL and a DEFAULT value inserted?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a table row that does not need a value (no error message if empty) but will insert a default value if empty, as in:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER rowname TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER rowname SET DEFAULT 0;
```

I set it up this way, but the value inserted is still NULL.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT NULL` clearly says the value for this column cannot be `NULL`. So there is no `NULL` value used for the column. But it can hold the integer value `0` as it is a valid integer value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange.  Given this table definition:

```
create table def ( i int not null default 0 );
```

This statement works:

```
insert into def () values ();
select * from def;

+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```

But this statement generates an error:

```
insert into def values( null );
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'i' cannot be null
```

So it seems that "not null default 0" will supply the default of 0 when the column is not explicitly assigned a value (which would normally be assigned a NULL), but does not allow NULL to be explicitly assigned because of the NOT NULL attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the value being inserted into the database is actually NULL, and that your programming language isn't just disregarding type and treating a 0 in the row as equivalent to NULL?  If your column is defined as `NOT NULL`, MySQL shouldn't even be allowing NULL at all, let alone use it as the default.